How can i controlling the ticks on the second axis?
enter image description here
import numpy as np import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
c=3.1
fig = plt.figure()    
ax1 = fig.add_subplot(111)    
ax2 = ax1.twiny()

xticks0 = np.array([1, 1.03, 1.2, 1.5, 2.06, 3.1, 6.2, 15.5], dtype = 'int_')


xvals = np.arange(3, 16, 0.00001)     
data = xvals     
ax1.plot(xvals, data)

ax1Ticks =xvals
ax2Ticks = xticks0

def tick_function(X):
    V = c/X
    return ["%.2f" % z for z in V]

ax2.set_xticks(ax2Ticks)
ax2.set_xbound(ax1.get_xbound())
ax2.set_xticklabels(tick_function(ax2Ticks))

ax1.set_xlabel("harmonic order") 
ax2.set_xlabel('Wavelength (micrometer)')
ax1.grid(True)
plt.xlim(xmin=3, xmax=15)
plt.tick_params(labelsize = 12 );

plt.show()

i want put specific ticks in top axis
But, it is not displayed.
what i want is
bottom axis 3~15 array
top axis 3.1/bottom axis (3, 2.5,2,1.5,1,0.5,0.2).

c*(1/4-1/6)⇒0.2583 and c*(1/14-1/16)⇒0.0276 Is it possible that your expectations are not realistic?

If I understood correctly, you would like to add a separate ticks on the top with some custom labels.
Here is a way you can do that

Define "real positions" where you would like to put your marks. This is 1, 1.03, ...
Define "custom labels" for these positions. Apply your function tick_function that will add custom labels

Here is code part that can help:
ax2 = ax1.twiny() # Secondary (top) axis
ax2_ticks = np.array([1, 1.03, 1.2, 1.5, 2.06, 3.1, 6.2, 15.5])
ax2_labels = tick_function(ax2_ticks) 


ax2.set_xticks(ax2_ticks)  
ax2.set_xticklabels(ax2_labels)
ax2.set_xlabel("Top Axis: Wavelength (micrometer)")

Here I fixed the whole code and seems that here is what is necessary:
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

def tick_function(X):
    V = c/X
    return ["%.2f" % z for z in V]

# Constants
c = 3.1
xvals = np.arange(3, 20, 0.00001)  # Primary axis values


fig, ax1 = plt.subplots(figsize=(12, 10))  # Primary axis (bottom)
ax2 = ax1.twiny() # Secondary (top) axis


ax1_ticks = np.arange(3, 16)  
ax1.set_xticks(ax1_ticks)  
ax1.set_xticklabels(ax1_ticks)  
ax1.set_xlabel("Botton Axis: Harmonic Order")


ax2_ticks = np.array([1, 1.03, 1.2, 1.5, 2.06, 3.1, 6.2, 15.5])
ax2_labels = tick_function(ax2_ticks)


ax2.set_xticks(ax2_ticks)  
ax2.set_xticklabels(ax2_labels)
ax2.set_xlabel("Top Axis: Wavelength (micrometer)")


ax1.set_xlim(3, 16) 
ax2.set_xbound(ax1.get_xbound()) 

# Add vertical lines if necessary
ax1.grid(True, which='both', axis='x') 
ax2.grid(True, which='both', axis='x') 


ax1.plot(xvals, xvals) 


plt.show()


still i can t get a sufficient tick in graph.
only the i can see is ticks in 1 , 0.5 , 0.2 micrometer.
now i use python3 what is your python  version?

Could you share what output do you expect? Did not get that to be honest :(
